# Unable to connect Oracle DB through Nodejs API deployed in Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, oracle19c, node-oracledb, instantclient

Can anyone help me to connect oracle DB through Nodejs api deployed in Google App Engine .
I referred this [link](https://quabr.com/58917589/connect-oracle-database-from-google-app-engine-with-node-js) to connect to DB .But it is not working.

Same code worked fine in local, where I refer oracle instant client from a local folder.

Below is the dockerfile I am using to install instantClient.But I can't  map the path properly.

```
FROM node:12.9.1-buster-slim

WORKDIR /tmp
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && apt-get install -y alien libaio1

RUN wget https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/oracle/instantclient/x86_64/getPackage/oracle-instantclient19.3-basiclite-19.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
RUN alien -i --scripts oracle-instantclient*.rpm
RUN rm -f oracle-instantclient19.3*.rpm && apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get -y clean

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied.
# Copying this separately prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN npm install --only=production

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . .

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Map what path?  Is there an error message somewhere?

Comment: Yes I meant path.
Thanks for your reply @ChristopherJones.I have fixed it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope my answer will help others who is looking for a solution .

I have used both dockerfile and app.yaml for deploying in App Engine .

I referred below link for OracleDB connection .It worked like a charm in local .But When I deployed to AppEngine I was not able to map the oracle instant client folder path.

So I installed the Oracle instantclient using Dockerfile.

```
# Use the official Node.js 12 image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/node

FROM node:12-buster-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1 wget unzip

WORKDIR /opt/oracle

RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *mql1* *ipc1* *jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \
    echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && ldconfig

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied.
# Copying this separately prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN npm install --only=production

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . .

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

App.yaml file

```
# [START appengine_websockets_yaml]
runtime: custom
env: flex
service: servicename
network:
  name: path
env_variables:

# Use only a single instance, so that this local-memory-only chat app will work
# consistently with multiple users. To work across multiple instances, an
# extra-instance messaging system or data store would be needed.
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
# [END appengine_websockets_yaml]
```

To initialize the OracleClient use below code

```
const ORACLE_CLIENT_PATH = process.env.ldconfig

exports.initializeOracleClient = async () => {
    oracledb.initOracleClient({ libDir: ORACLE_CLIENT_PATH });
}
```

Comment: Because you're on Linux, the call to `initOracleClient` doesn't do what you think it does.  It does force the client libraries to be loaded when it is called but the system library search path (via ldconfig or LD_LIBRARY_PATH) **must still be set before** the process starts.  In fact, if you pass a different client path to the one set in the environment you could end up with a clash.  The `initOracleClient(libDir)` usage is really only helpful on Windows and macOS.  Note that on all platforms, if you don't call `initOracleClient`, then the libs are loaded when the first connection is opened.